# Generation of random integers between two set values in C

Tags: c

I'm looking to implement something similar to python's random.randint in C.

I would do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
srand(time(NULL));

int randInt(int lBound, int uBound){
    return (rand()%(uBound-lBound+1))+lbound;
}
```

but if RAND_MAX is not a multiple of uBound, then distribution will be slight skewed.

Is there a quick and dirty way that's better?

Comment: Why you dont use `srand (time(NULL))` as seed?

Comment: That function is wrong, it should be `(rand()%(uBound-lBound+1))+lbound`

Comment: no interest in using gnu's gsl_rng_uniform_int ?

Comment: @Alexandre&interjay.  Thanks, I missed those, and have edited the question

Comment: @TomSwifty I was unaware of it's existence and will take a look at it, but I'm still curious as to other ways of going about it.

Comment: gsl will help you avoid reinventing the wheel, but it is always a good idea to aim for a deeper understanding by writing your own

Comment: @JohnGann [`rand()` should be considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) I would highly suggest looking at library functions if you want a uniform distribution

Comment: The issue is when `RAND_MAX` isn't a multiple of `(uBound - lBound + 1)`, not just `uBound`.

Answer (score 0):

If avoiding skew is important then you need to do something like this.

```
int randInt(int lBound, int uBound){
    int rangesize = uBound-lBound+1; 
    if ((rangesize - 1 > RAND_MAX) || (rangesize < 0) || (lBound > uBound)) {
        // run in circles, scream and shout
    }
    int limit;
    if (rangesize < RAND_MAX) {
        limit = RAND_MAX - (((RAND_MAX % rangesize) + 1) % rangesize);
    } else {
        limit = RAND_MAX;
    ]
    int rv;
    do {
        rv = rand();
    } while (rv > limit);
    return rv % rangesize + lbound;
}
```

Comment: That's a good way to approach the solution, but it has some issues: It doesn't work on platforms where `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX`, because `RAND_MAX+1` will overflow. It also doesn't work when `uBound-lBound > RAND_MAX`, or when `uBound-lBound+1` doesn't fit in an `int`.

Comment: Issues fixed, I think.